# reformat a select list into ordered list

Tags: hooks

I have a module "custom search" installed and its producing the taxonomy list as a drop list "select list", is there a way that i can hook into that list and reformat it to be an ordered list.
this is what I have so far

```
<select class="custom-search-selector custom-search-vocabulary form-select" id="edit-custom-search-vocabulary-2" name="custom_search_vocabulary_2">
<option value="c-all" selected="selected">-Any-</option>
<option value="c-10">  Algeria</option>
<option value="c-27">  Bahrain</option>
<option value="c-8">  Eygipt</option>
</select>
```

to be

```
<ul class="custom-search-selector custom-search-vocabulary form-select" id="edit-custom-search-vocabulary-2" name="custom_search_vocabulary_2">
<li value="c-all">-Any-</li>
<li value="c-10">Algeria</li>
<li value="c-27">Bahrain</li>
<li value="c-8">Eygipt</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What reason changing input form to html element?

Comment: Client request to be honest.

Comment: hook_form_alter should do but then your form won't make sense for validation and submission. And how is the user supposed to choose a value anyway ???